# Linking boost libraries in xcode

Tags: c++, boost, osx-mountain-lion, xcode4.5

I have boost 1_46_1 in this path: /Users/ramy/Documents/C++ .
In a C++ xcode project I have modified the user header search paths, and added this directory : /Users/ramy/Documents/C++/boost_1_46_1 .
I am trying to include boost/regex.hpp .The file is there: if I go to /Users/ramy/Documents/C++/boost_1_46_1/boost there is regex.hpp, but I get an error when trying to build the project: boost/regex.hpp: file not found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hmm... Do you know that Regex Boost is not header-only ?

You may have to build Boost and link to the libraries ( [linkage options](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/configuration/linkage.html) )

Comment: Ok but this is for windows, what about os x?